# Difference between param[out] and return in doxygen?

Tags: doxygen

What is the difference between [\param[out]](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdparam) and [\return](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdreturn) in Doxygen? They both seem to document the output / return of a function. Is the difference due to `void` functions which don't have a return value and only `param[out]` would be valid?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Out parameters are different from return values. Take this example in C:

```c
/**
 * \param[in]  val      Value calculations are based off.
 * \param[out] variable Function output is written to this variable.
 *
 * \return Nothing
 */
void modify_value(int val, int *variable)
{
    val *= 5;
    int working = val % 44;
    *variable = working;
}
```

The function returns nothing, but the value to which `variable` points is changed, hence we call it an output parameter. It represents an 'output' of the function in that we expect it to be modified somehow by the function. `val`, on the other hand, is an 'input' parameter because it is not modified (and, indeed, cannot be modified from the perspective of the function's caller, since it is passed as a value).

Here's a slightly more useful and realistic example:

```c
typedef struct data {
    int i;
    int j;
    ...
} data;

/**
 * \param[in]  val Initialising parameter for data.
 * \param[out] dat Data pointer where the new object should be stored.
 *
 * \return True if the object was created, false if not
 *         (i.e., we're out of memory)
 */
bool create_data(int val, data **dat)
{
    data *newdata;
    newdata = (data*)malloc(sizeof(data));
    if(newdata == NULL)
    {
        *dat = NULL;
        return false;
    }
    newdata->i = val;
    *dat = newdata;
    return true;
}
```

In this case, we construct some complex object inside the function. We return a simple status flag that lets the user know the object creation was successful. But we pass out the newly-created object using an out parameter.

(Although, of course, this function could easily just return a pointer. Some functions are more complex!)

Comment: Nice explanation. In rare cases, this is even done in Java, where an object is filled with the output values.

Answer (score 6):

As a simpler answer, `[out]` parameters are only for results returned via parameters not the return value. It is quite reasonable to have a function which has a return value and also has optional return data, eg: one I'm just writing has the signature:

```
  /**
  Determine UTF type of a file. 
  Unless a UTF8 file has a BOM, it is regarded as unknown.

  @param [in] path Path to file suitable for ifstream
  @param [out] bomWasFound optional return flag to indicate a BOM was found, really only useful for UTF8
  @return an enum indicating type, default utf_unknown
  */
  UtfType CheckFileType(const std::string& path, bool* bomWasFound=0);
```