# Using param[out] in Doxygen when setting a class property

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am using Doxygen to document my c++ code. I have read this StackOverflow post about the difference between \return and \param[out]

[Difference between param[out] and return in doxygen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7730409/difference-between-paramout-and-return-in-doxygen)

param[out] is used if you are setting something with a pointer in your function. If I have a method which sets a variable within its class is it still correct to use param[out] (the function is void)?

An example of what I mean - I have a method to convert polar coordinate inputs to Cartesian.

```
classConstructor(azimuth, elevation, roll)
{
     //set azimuth, elevation, roll
     convertToCartesian(azimuth, elevation, roll)
}

convertToCartesian(azimuth, elevation, roll)
{
     //someCode
     xPos = calcVector.X
     yPos = calcVector.Y
     zPos = calcVector.Z
}
```

xPos, yPos and xPos are private variables in my class, they are used later (accessed via getters);

Comment: No. `param[out]` is used for function *parameters* that get changed by the function.

Comment: Is there a way this type of operation should be documented then?

Comment: In the description, perhaps, using natural language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

param[out] is used for pointers passed into a function. Anything external that is modified from within a function should be documented with comments.

*Note: If you can't explain why you are editing variable inside a function which weren't passed in then you are probably writing bad code.*